# Burn ISO file to Flash Drive with Raspbian

Tags: image

Recently my Windows 10 Tablet stuck at booting after update, so I want to burn the WIN10.ISO to flash drive to run repair but don’t know how on Raspbian. The only PC available at hand is my Raspberry PI 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

connect flash drive

unmount it

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/your/WIN10.ISO of=/dev/sdX bs=4M status=progress; sync
```

replace `/dev/sdX` by the correct device letter of your flash drive (to find it out: mount the flash drive, run `df -h` to see mounted devices, unmount it)

> Note: use of the dd tool can overwrite any partition of your machine. If you specify the wrong device in the instructions [..], you could delete your primary Linux partition. Please be careful.

source: [Raspberry Pi Documentation - Installing operating system images on Linux](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `dd`

```
dd if=ISO of=/dev/sda
```

Should work

**NOTE** `dd` will OVERWRITE anything, without warning, so double check your flash drive location.

You should ensure the flash drive is **NOT MOUNTED**

You may need to precede `dd` with `sudo`